# How to close VirtualBox "Detached/Headless" console window?

Tags: virtualbox

I have been using VirtualBox on a Ubuntu machine for a long time to host guest machines that run in "headless" mode.

It used to be that when I would open the console of one of these machines, the "Close" dialog box would offer the option to just close the window but leave the machine running.

I just upgraded to the newest (5.1.28) and that option is no longer available. I can start a VM in headless or detachable mode, but then I can't exit the GUI and still leave the machine running?

Where did this option go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VirtualBox 5.1.x (originally released 2016-07-12), the changelog says:

> GUI: the *Detach UI* action is now a part of the VM Machine menu